# Separador de miles aceptando números negativos

Tags: javascript

tengo este código, el cual es un separador de miles pero tengo un problema con los números negativos
¿Que le falta al código para poder aceptar n° negativos? por ejemplo: -123456

Entiendo que en el `value.replace(/\D/g, "")` es el que permite ingresar solo números, por lo cual mi problema es como poder modificarlo y que se pueda agregar un signo `-`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".number").on({"focus": function(event) {
            $(event.target).select();
        },
        "keyup": function(event) {
            $(event.target).val(function(index, value) {
                return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
                .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ".");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="number"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías validar si `value` empieza con `-` y si ese es el caso, sacarlo temporalmente y agregarlo luego de aplicar la limpieza y formato.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".number").on({
    "focus": function(event) {
      $(event.target).select();
    },
    "keyup": function(event) {
      $(event.target).val(function(index, value) {
        // Controlamos el signo
        let sign = '';
        if (value[0] == '-') {
          value = value.substr(1);
          sign = '-';
        }

        return sign + value.replace(/\D/g, "")
          .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ".");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="number" />
```